# How to count selected checkboxes in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I am needing to add bit of text in the sidebar of the following code. In each  section, I need to have a count of the number of checkboxes selected. Is it at all possible to do this in a functional component as I have? Any examples that I have found so far are only for class components. I would like to keep it as a functional component if possible.

I have the code below, but here is a working version too:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-jgmof?file=/index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { categoryData } from "./data";

const Menu = (props) => {
  const [showPanel, togglePanel] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MenuWrapper>
      <p>Showing 20 results</p>

      <div className="button-wrapper">
        <p>Filter By</p>

        {categoryData.map((categorybutton, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <button key={i} onClick={() => togglePanel(!showPanel)}>
              {categorybutton.category}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}

        <div>
          {showPanel && (
            <Sidebar>
              {categoryData.map((categorysection, i) => (
                <details className="dropdown-header">
                  <summary>{categorysection.category}</summary>

                  {categorysection.data.map((categorylabel, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="vehicle1"
                        name="vehicle1"
                        value="Bike"
                      />
                      <label for="vehicle1">{categorylabel.label}</label>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </details>
              ))}
            </Sidebar>
          )}
        </div>

        <p>Toggle</p>
        <p>Clear all filters</p>
      </div>
    </MenuWrapper>
  );
};

const MenuWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
`;

const Sidebar = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  text-align: left;

  .dropdown-header {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 20px;
  }
`;

ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```
export const categoryData = [
  {
    category: "user",
    data: [
      { checked: false, value: "Me", label: "Me" },
      { checked: false, value: "Kids", label: "Kids" },
      { checked: false, value: "Guestroom", label: "Guestroom" }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "comfort",
    data: [
      { checked: false, value: "Ultra-Soft", label: "Ultra-Soft" },
      { checked: false, value: "Soft", label: "Soft" },
      { checked: false, value: "Medium", label: "Medium" },
      { checked: false, value: "Medium-Firm", label: "Medium-Firm" },
      { checked: false, value: "Firm", label: "Firm" },
      { checked: false, value: "Ultra-Firm", label: "Ultra-Firm" },
      { checked: false, value: "Unsure", label: "Unsure" }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "type",
    data: [
      { checked: false, value: "Pillow Top", label: "Pillow Top" },
      { checked: false, value: "Open Coil", label: "Open Coil" },
      { checked: false, value: "Pocketed Coil", label: "Pocketed Coil" },
      { checked: false, value: "Quantum Coil", label: "Quantum Coil" },
      { checked: false, value: "Memory Foam", label: "Memory Foam" },
      { checked: false, value: "Latex", label: "Latex" },
      { checked: false, value: "Unsure", label: "Unsure" }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "budget",
    data: [
      { checked: false, value: 500, label: "Under $500" },
      { checked: false, value: 1000, label: "$501 - $1000" },
      { checked: false, value: 1600, label: "1001 - $1600" },
      { checked: false, value: 2500, label: "$1601 - $2500" },
      { checked: false, value: 2501, label: "$2500 and up" },
      { checked: false, value: "Unsure", label: "Unsure" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wan't to show the total number of selected items on each category.

It would be easy if we'll create a new component for the section that will have it's own state tracking its selected items.

Let's call it `CategorySection`. It would then have a `selected` state that will be an `array` (empty by default) of its selected items. To update our `selected` state, we have to fireup a function everytime any of the checkbox is changed — if the checkbox is checked, we add the current item to our `selected` state otherwise it will be removed.

Then to display the total selected items, we can simply count the length of our `selected` state.

```js
function CategorySection({ categorysection }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  function onChange(event, item) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setSelected([...selected, item]);
    } else {
      setSelected((prev) =>
        prev.filter((currItem) => currItem.value !== item.value)
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <details className="dropdown-header">
      <summary>
        {categorysection.category}{" "}
        {selected.length > 0 ? selected.length : null}
      </summary>

      {categorysection.data.map((categorylabel, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={categorylabel.value}
            name="vehicle1"
            value="Bike"
            onChange={(event) => onChange(event, categorylabel)}
          />
          <label for={categorylabel.value}>{categorylabel.label}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </details>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React PlayGround (forked)]

PS: You should have a unique `id` for every checkbox on your page.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would it also be possible to get the {selected.length > 0 ? selected.length : null} from the summary into the buttons, so that the buttons could also show the count for their respective categories?

Comment: With the current code, I would do it like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-co324?file=/index.js). You might want to checkout [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)